# GMaps: Multiple markers loading with delay

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I've got about 100 addresses (markers) with unknown lat/long. The geocoding takes really long after about 10 markers. Is there any way I can speed this up? Without saving the lat/long values? In GMap v3 oder v2.

Maybe bing maps or Open Street Map is better?

Comment: What country? Also, are you able to save lat/lon values if the Terms of Service permitted it?

Comment: Why not save them? The houses are not about to move. ;-)

Comment: All places are in Cologne, Germany. I thought I can skip those two vales in my DB, when I can calculate them on request. Anyway, changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can speed this up?

No. The rate limit and quota is there to prevent you from abusing the service.  It is possible that a paid license might give you a higher limit (but I don't think so).

> Without saving the lat/long values?

The only way to geocode the addresses faster is to create your own geocoder or pay for access to a non-Google geocoder, I don't have any experience with non-Google free geocoders.  There is free code and data available for the US (the free data is lower quality than Google's).  Other countries will be more expensive.

The best solution is to geocode the addresses off-line and use the resulting coordinates to display the markers.

> In GMap v3 or v2.

The v2 API has less than a year left in its official life, not recommended for new development.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my CMS to save the lat/long values for all places when I save the page with a place attached. I don't think there will be more than 2500 pages saved a month :-)